# Input text field filtering using jquery causes cursor to jump in IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, input, cursor-position

I am filtering input in input text fields, for example:

And I am filtering input on the fly, like removing non-numeric characters.

```
$("#txtlevel").bind('keyup', function(evt)
{
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');   /* Remove any non-digit characters */
    if ( value.length > 1 )
    {
        value = value.replace(/^[ 0]/g,'');   /* Remove any leading spaces or zeros */
    }
    $(this).val(value);
}
```

This works great in Firefox, but in IE and Chrome the cursor jumps to the end of the input field every time.  How can I prevent this or reset the cursor position?  I've seen code to do it for textfields but not input text fields.

Comment: works fine for me here is the link

http://jsfiddle.net/SJmCY/

Comment: @Kishore That does not work for me.  The cursor still goes to the end of the textbox when i am editing the start of a number

Comment: Sorry, put my response in answer block below.  Try the example input scenario. You should see the problem then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use keyup and do regex replace (in other words, setting the `value`), the cursor will jump to the end. If your goal is to allow only numeric keys (plus backspace, delete), try this:

```
$("#txtlevel").bind('keydown', function(event) {
    // Allow only backspace, delete, left and right arrows, return and tab
    if (event.keyCode == 46 || 
        event.keyCode == 8 || 
        event.keyCode == 37 || 
        event.keyCode == 39 || 
        event.keyCode == 13 || 
        event.keyCode == 9) {
        // let it happen
    }
    else {
        // stop the keypress if not a number
        if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57 ) {
            event.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
});
```

To cancel out non-numeric events on paste, bind it to `paste` event:

```
$("#txtlevel").bind('paste', function(e){ 
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');   /* Remove any non-digit characters */
    if ( value.length > 1 ) {
        value = value.replace(/^[ 0]/g,'');   /* Remove any leading spaces or zeros */
    }
    $(this).val(value);
});
```

Comment: That worked great!  I also added tab, return, left and right arrows, so my if looks like:

Comment: if ( evt.keyCode == 46 || evt.keyCode == 8 || evt.keyCode == 37 || evt.keyCode == 39 || evt.keyCode == 13 || evt.keyCode == 9 ) {

Comment: Great! I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I woke up this morning thinking about this and realized cut/pasting won't work this way.  If I add the ctrl key and ctrl-v keys, it allows them to paste anything.  Is there a way to add cut/paste to your answer but capture what is being pasted and 'screen it'?

Comment: Yup. See my update. I'm using your code since I think that would suffice, but feel free to change it as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can save and restore the cursor position. That way the cursor wont jump to the end of the text

```
$("#txtlevel").bind('keyup', function(evt)
{
    var pos = evt.target.selectionStart; // Save cursor position
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');   /* Remove any non-digit characters */
    if ( value.length > 1 )
    {
        value = value.replace(/^[ 0]/g,'');   /* Remove any leading spaces or zeros */
    }
    $(this).val(value);
    evt.target.selectionEnd = pos; // Restore cursor position
}
```